# Problem with Google Checkout Subscription

Tags: c#, google-checkout, subscription

I am trying to create a subscription in Google Checkout.  The subscription is created but it charges at the end of the period not the beginning.  I admit that I only waited a few hours to make sure it was going to charge, so if i just need to give it a while longer let me know.

I have tried to match the code exactly as seen here: http://code.google.com/apis/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_Beta_Subscriptions.html#Google_Handled_Subscriptions

Has anyone ever been able to get this to charge at the beginning not the end?

I have the following code:

```
        string digitalContent = "Congratulations! Your subscription is being set up. Feel free to log onto <a href='{0}'>{0}</a> and try it out!";

        digitalContent = String.Format(digitalContent, String.Format(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ContinueShoppingUrl"], this.Transaction.ID));

        CheckoutShoppingCartRequest Req = GCheckoutButton1.CreateRequest();
        Req.ContinueShoppingUrl = String.Format(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ContinueShoppingUrl"], this.Transaction.ID);
        Req.EditCartUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EditCartUrl"];

        SubscriptionPayment payment = new SubscriptionPayment();
        payment.MaximumCharge = 0;
        payment.Times = 12;

        Subscription subscription = new Subscription();
        subscription.Period = GCheckout.AutoGen.DatePeriod.MONTHLY;
        subscription.Type = SubscriptionType.google;
        subscription.StartDate = DateTime.Now;
        subscription.NoChargeAfter = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(12);

        ShoppingCartSubscriptionItem subscriptionItem = new ShoppingCartSubscriptionItem();
        subscriptionItem.Price = 0;
        subscriptionItem.Name = "Subscription to [redacted]";
        subscriptionItem.Description = "Subscription to [redacted]";
        subscriptionItem.Quantity = 1;
        subscriptionItem.Subscription = subscription;
        subscriptionItem.DigitalContent = new DigitalItem(digitalContent, false);

        ShoppingCartSubscriptionItem subscriptionItem2 = new ShoppingCartSubscriptionItem();
        subscriptionItem2.Name = "";
        subscriptionItem2.Description = this.Transaction.ID.ToString();
        subscriptionItem2.Quantity = 1;


        payment.MaximumCharge = 15.00M;
        subscriptionItem2.Price = 15.00M;

        subscription.RecurrentItem = subscriptionItem2;
        subscription.AddSubscriptionPayment(payment);

        Req.AddItem(subscriptionItem);

        GCheckoutResponse Resp = Req.Send();
```

Which generates the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
- <checkout-shopping-cart xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://checkout.google.com/schema/2">
- <shopping-cart>
- <items>
- <item>
- <subscription no-charge-after="2012-06-28T06:54:15.9492-07:00" period="MONTHLY" start-date="2011-06-28T06:54:15.9492-07:00" type="google">
- <payments>
- <subscription-payment times="12">
  <maximum-charge currency="USD">15.00</maximum-charge> 
  </subscription-payment>
  </payments>
- <recurrent-item>
  <tax-table-selector /> 
  <item-name /> 
  <item-description>3119988d-9ce4-43d2-b2a4-6f9bf1fe6a78</item-description> 
  <unit-price currency="USD">15.00</unit-price> 
  <quantity>1</quantity> 
  </recurrent-item>
  </subscription>
- <digital-content>
  <description>Congratulations! Your subscription is being set up. Feel free to log onto &#x3c;a href='[redacted]/Transactions/3119988d-9ce4-43d2-b2a4-6f9bf1fe6a78'&#x3e;[redacted]/Transactions/3119988d-9ce4-43d2-b2a4-6f9bf1fe6a78&#x3c;/a&#x3e; and try it out!</description> 
  <display-disposition>PESSIMISTIC</display-disposition> 
  </digital-content>
  <tax-table-selector /> 
  <item-name>Subscription to Escrow Coordinator Plus</item-name> 
  <item-description>Subscription to Escrow Coordinator Plus</item-description> 
  <unit-price currency="USD">0</unit-price> 
  <quantity>1</quantity> 
  </item>
  </items>
  </shopping-cart>
- <checkout-flow-support>
- <merchant-checkout-flow-support>
  <edit-cart-url>[redacted]</edit-cart-url> 
  <continue-shopping-url>[redacted]/Transactions/3119988d-9ce4-43d2-b2a4-6f9bf1fe6a78</continue-shopping-url> 
  </merchant-checkout-flow-support>
  </checkout-flow-support>
  </checkout-shopping-cart>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the google api site: http://code.google.com/apis/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_Beta_Subscriptions.html
find the section for "Submitting an Order with a Subscription".
I will try to find the link, but i read that to charge at the beginning, you have to have a second item in the cart.  So one item charges now, then recurring item at the end of each period.  It was in the API docs